# How to scale a drawing in animateinline loop and maintain same center point for the scaled structures

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to scale a structure in for my animation.  I used scale option for this purpose, but it is causing the structure to move to new position. I want the cross shapes to scale but have the same center position. Here is my code, help is apreciated.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Warsaw}} 
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title[]{My Presentation}
\author[Raghuram Dharmavarapu]{Raghu}
\date{}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Animated Integral}

\begin{animateinline}[loop, poster = first,controls]{3}
    \multiframe{11}{i=0+1}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.8]
    \useasboundingbox (-4,-5) rectangle (10,5);
    \onslide<1->
    \filldraw[blue!40!black] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2.35,1) --(-0.35,1)--cycle;
    \filldraw[blue!40!white] (-0.35,1) --(0.25,1.6) -- (1.75,1.6) -- (2.35,1) --cycle;

    \filldraw[gray!30!white,scale = 0.08] (10,16) -- (13,16) -- (12.9,17) -- (14.5,17) --(14.2,18.25)--(12.7,18.25)--(12.6,19)--(10.4,19)--(10.3,18.25)--(8.8,18.25)--(8.5,17)--(10.1,17)--cycle;
    \filldraw[gray!90!white,scale = 0.08] (8.5,17)--(8.6,14.5)--(10.05,14.5)--(10,16)--(10.1,17)--cycle;
    \filldraw[gray!90!black,scale = 0.08] (10,16) -- (10.1,14) -- (12.9,14) -- (13,16)-- cycle;
    \filldraw[gray!90!white,scale = 0.08] (14.5,17) --(14.4,14.5) --(12.95,14.5) --(13,16) -- (12.9,17) --cycle;

\onslide<2->
    \filldraw[blue!40!black] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2.35,1) --(-0.35,1)--cycle;
    \filldraw[blue!40!white] (-0.35,1) --(0.25,1.6) -- (1.75,1.6) -- (2.35,1) --cycle;

    \filldraw[gray!30!white,scale = 0.08+\i/100] (10,16) -- (13,16) -- (12.9,17) -- (14.5,17) --(14.2,18.25)--(12.7,18.25)--(12.6,19)--(10.4,19)--(10.3,18.25)--(8.8,18.25)--(8.5,17)--(10.1,17)--cycle;
    \filldraw[gray!90!white,scale = 0.08+\i/100] (8.5,17)--(8.6,14.5)--(10.05,14.5)--(10,16)--(10.1,17)--cycle;
    \filldraw[gray!90!black,scale = 0.08+\i/100] (10,16) -- (10.1,14) -- (12.9,14) -- (13,16)-- cycle;
    \filldraw[gray!90!white,scale = 0.08+\i/100] (14.5,17) --(14.4,14.5) --(12.95,14.5) --(13,16) -- (12.9,17) --cycle;


      \draw[->] (-3,-4) -- (10,-4) node[right] {$\lambda$};
      \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (10,0) node[right] {$\lambda$};
      \draw[->] (-2.5,-4.5) -- (-2.5,4) node[above] {$|E|$};
      \draw[->] (4,-4.5) -- (4,4) node[above] {$\angle E$};
      \draw[thick, dashed,domain=-1.5:3,samples = 100,smooth,variable=\x,blue] plot ({\x},{-4+3*pow(2.71,-(pow(\x+1-(\i/10*1.5),2))/0.05)});
      \draw[thick,domain=-1.5:3,smooth,samples = 100,variable=\x,red] plot ({\x},{-4+3*pow(2.71,-(pow(\x-2+(\i/10*1.5),2))/0.05)}); 

      \draw[thick, dashed,domain=-2:2,smooth,samples = 100,variable=\x,green] plot ({\x+6+(\i/10*1)},{-2.5+rad(atan(\x*3.5))});
      \draw[thick,domain=-2:2,smooth,samples = 100,variable=\x,magenta] plot ({\x+8 
      -(\i/10*1)},{-2.5+rad(atan(\x*3.5))});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Actually, I didn't understand your request.

Comment: Could you please explain more what you want to achieve? I am particulary wondering about the `\onslide` commands in the `tikzpicture`. If I remove them, I get a nice animation. The number 2 in `\onslide<2->` is not the frame number of `\multiframe`.

Comment: If I replace the `\onslide` commands by `\ifnum\i>0
    \filldraw[blue!40!black] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2.35,1) --(-0.35,1)--cycle;
 \fi` and `\ifnum\i>1
    \filldraw[blue!40!black] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2.35,1) --(-0.35,1)--cycle;
 \fi` I obtain a beautiful animation. The `ifthen` package is not needed in your code. And `beamer` has its own means to animate things, if you go for it, you could find `\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}` useful.

Comment: I want to show the blue block with cross on top first. Then on the next slide I want to show the animation where the cross of the blue block gets bigger and bigger But my problem is that the cross is not sitting on the blue block as it gets bigger.